# How to upgrade big Ruby on Rails project from Rails version 4.2.2 to 6.0.2.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a huge rails web application with wide user base which runs on Rails 4.2.2 and Ruby 2.2.2 as of now. I simply want to upgrade the whole application to the latest version of Ruby i.e. 2.5.0 and Rails 6.0.2.2. 
The reason for upgrade being I want to integrate a completely separate React.js frontend and a separate Rails backend. Other reasons for upgradation being deprecating older version of gems and rails. 
I have tried researching a lot for this. I have also tried the : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html guides. But everything out there is so vague and haphazard. I havent found any clear cut method until now following which I can upgrade my rails application smoothly. 
Please help.

Comment: Key to successful migration is having comprehensive test coverage. First migrate Ruby to higher version and than Rails on same way to immediately higher versions one by one.

Comment: It won't be a "copy new files in" job. You should duplicate the app on an entirely separate box, update ruby and rails and fix issues as they occur. They will. You're not getting away without getting your hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend you to do is to upgrade to Rails 5.x.x first and than to 6.x.x you can use those guides and follow step by step:

https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/rails/upgrades/upgrade-rails-from-4-2-to-5-0.html
https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-6

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a progressive update for both Ruby and Rails. I would for example start by updating Ruby from 2.2.2 to 2.3, using the Release notes as guide of what things have changed:
https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released
Once that work (which would be easy to check if you have high test coverage), I would continue with Ruby 2.4 and so on.
Ruby minor releases (for example 2.2.2 to 2.2.3) shouldn't include breakable changes, so you can just go from 2.2.2 to 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 ...

Also, note that the last version Ruby is 2.7.1 and not 2.5.0. Another good reason to update your Ruby version is that it is not maintained any more and it does not receives security fixes. 2.5.8 is in security maintenance phase, which means that it won't be maintained anymore soon. You may want to update to at least Ruby 2.6.

Regarding Rails, you can find the release notes here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html (just change the number in url to get the information of a different release).